# Double negation in Lucene query

Tags: solr, lucene, solr-query-syntax

Lets say i have a binary field **checked**
Lets also assume that 3 documents out of 10 has checked:1 others checked:0

When I search in lucene

```
checked:1 - returns correct result (3)
checked:0 - returns correct result (7)
-checked:1 - returns correct result (7)
-checked:0 - returns correct result (3)

BUT

-(-(checked:1)) - suddenly returns wrong result (10, i.e. entire data set).
```

Any idea why lucene query parse acts so weird

Comment: You must have at least positive term in your query. Is this what you pasted the whole query, or just a part of it?

Comment: this the whole query. What do u mean? Could you, please, elaborate in answer maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research and trial and error and building up on answer from midas, I have came up with the method to resolve this inconsistency. When I say inconsistency, I mean from a common sense view for a user. From information retrieval prospective, midas has linked an interesting article, which explains why such a query makes no sense.
So, the trick is to keep each negative expression with [MatchAllDocsQueryNode](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_6_1/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/flexible/core/nodes/MatchAllDocsQueryNode.html) class, namely the rewritten query has to look like this:

```
 -(-(checked:1 *:*) *:*)
```

Then the query will produce the expected result. I have accomplished it by writing my own nodeprocessor class, which performs necessary operations.

Answer (score 2):

Each Lucene query has to contain at least one positive term (either MUST/+ or SHOULD) so it matches at least one document. So your queries `-checked:1` and `-checked:0` are invalid, and I am surprised you are getting *any* results.

These queries should (most likely) look like this:

- `+*:* -checked:1`
- `+*:* -checked:0`

Getting back to your problem: double negation [makes no sense](http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/lucene/java-user/31402?do=post_view_flat) in Lucene. Why would you have double negation, what are you trying to query?

Generally speaking, don't look at Lucene query operators (! & |) as Boolean operators, [they aren't exactly what you think they are](http://searchhub.org/2011/12/28/why-not-and-or-and-not/).

Comment: why does lucene query have to have at least one positive term? I agree double negation doesnt make sense, but why result is not correct? Isnt -- = +?

Comment: You need to read the article I linked to understand how matching/scoring works, this will answer your questions.

Comment: Ok, i will. Seems like Ill have to think about implementing a custom parser, 'cause this doesnt make much sense to me tbh. Thx!

Comment: As a point of interest, `-checked:1` returns the stated result because the solr query parser has some special handling to parse that into `*:* -checked:1`.  The parenthesized terms aren't so handled, so the query becomes `*:* -(-(checked:1))`, and everything - (nothing) = everything.  (Personally, I think this special syntax, as well as Lucene's AND, OR and NOT operators may *cause* more confusion that it solves)

Comment: OP said _When I search in lucene_ (no mention of Solr) hence my doubts. Anyway, thanks for clarification.